# Consider the following joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability, statistics

$$f(x, y) = c(x + 3y), 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1,$$
and $0$ otherwise. Find:
(a) the value of $c$

apparently the answer is $1/2$ but I got $4/3$. I took the double integral with lower limits $0$ and upper limits $1$. Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
1 &= \int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)\ dy\ dx\\
&= \int_0^1\int_0^1c(x+3y)\ dy\ dx\\
&= c\int_0^1 \left[xy + \frac{3y^2}{2}\right]_0^1dx\\
&= c\int_0^1\left(x+\frac32\right)dx\\
&= c\left[\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{3x}2\right]_0^1\\
&= c\cdot2\\
c &= \frac12
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I see, I pulled out each part of the function so like integral then x then integral then 3y and when I had 3/2 by itself I pulled it out like an idiot. Thank you.